# shortening my 'and/or' code using parentheses

Tags: python

I want to shorten this code:

```
if (a+b+c == 1000 and a**2 + b**2 == c**2) or (a+b+c == 1000 and a**2 + c**2 == b**2) or (a+b+c == 1000 and b**2 + c**2 == a**2)
```

into:

```
if a+b+c == 1000 and (a**2 + b**2 == c**2 or a**2 + c**2 == b**2 or b**2 + c**2 == a**2)
```

or to be more simple:

```
(A and B) or (A and C) or (A and D) <=> A and (B or C or D)
```

Is this reasonable? It seems to work when I run the code, but I'm not sure it's the proper way. Is there a better way to shorten this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

In mathematical notation, the following equation would hold:

```
(A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ D) = A ∧ (B ∨ C ∨ D)
```

That is usually called normalization as CNF or DNF form.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean logic  says it is equivalent. 
But a better approach would be "test driven development" : first write tests of all possible results. Then run them against your first implementation and then against your refactored implementation.

Update, based on Cireo's answer :

```
import itertools
for a, b, c, d in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=4):
    print('%5s | %5s | %5s | %5s || %5s || %5s') % (a, b, c, d, (a and b) or (a and c) or (a and d), a and (b or c or d))

 True |  True |  True |  True ||  True ||  True
 True |  True |  True | False ||  True ||  True
 True |  True | False |  True ||  True ||  True
 True |  True | False | False ||  True ||  True
 True | False |  True |  True ||  True ||  True
 True | False |  True | False ||  True ||  True
 True | False | False |  True ||  True ||  True
 True | False | False | False || False || False
False |  True |  True |  True || False || False
False |  True |  True | False || False || False
False |  True | False |  True || False || False
False |  True | False | False || False || False
False | False |  True |  True || False || False
False | False |  True | False || False || False
False | False | False |  True || False || False
False | False | False | False || False || False
```

There it is proved that the two statements are equivalent for all values of all variables.

Comment: Actually, in programming, it is mostly better to do the maths than to brute force correlations.

Comment: @Uriel ok, then how do you prove you're doing the math correctly **and** that your language implements it correctly ?

Comment: A language implements maths correctly (considered it is defined to), because a language is just a bunch of rules and syntax. If you're doubting whether the CPython implementation (that's what you use) implements is correctly, rest assured, that's an open source one maintained by expert devs, mathmaticians and people that messed with compilers and interpreters for years. If I question them for that stuff, I might as well reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'd say that working out the better formulation is "doing the math"

Comment: @Baldrickk work it out using boolean logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Comment: and that's not math?

Comment: @Uriel ok, let's admit cpython is perfect. It still does not prove you doing the math correctly. Only a truth table proves it. Plus it is so easy to built it using the language.

Comment: I did. Go into the wikipedia I posted, section `Conversion into CNF`.

Comment: And just for your reference, in python you can just `all((a, b, c, d, (a and b) or (a and c) or (a and d) == a and (b or c or d)) for a, b, c, d in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=4))` instead of fancy formatting

Comment: @Uriel, one can state anything on wikipedia. CNF has been proven, with truth table.

Comment: "CNF has been proven" what does that mean? cpython implements boolean logics, not otherwise. CNF is just a form, it can't be proven and dont need to be.

Comment: @Uriel, you're right, reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Definition and other articles, distributivity in Boolean algebra is an axiom and not a theorem. And thus, has not to be proven. The truth table I proposed just proves that python implementation is correct. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  As Uriel mentions, this is mathematically sound. Furthermore, you have already noticed that the notation is supported in python.  The below truth table shows that it is also evaluated as expected:

```
>>> for a, b, c in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=3):
...   print('%5s | %5s | %5s || %5s') % (a, b, c, (a or b or c))
... 
 True |  True |  True ||  True
 True |  True | False ||  True
 True | False |  True ||  True
 True | False | False ||  True
False |  True |  True ||  True
False |  True | False ||  True
False | False |  True ||  True
False | False | False || False
```